# Does Twitter Bootstrap conflict with any major libraries?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know it works with fine with jQuery (in no-conflict mode), but are there any widely-used libraries out there that Bootstrap does *not* work with?

Comment: It works fine with jQuery even without no-conflict mode.

Comment: It would potentially conflict with another grid framework, just becareful.

Answer (score 1):

There are some naming conflicts with **jQuery UI**, which should be avoidable using Bootstrap's `noConflict` method.

There have been some `show`/`hide` event namespacing and `trigger()` related conflicts reported with **Prototype.js**, although those were last mentioned several versions ago. Not sure whether they're still true, but I'd err on the side of the issues still existing.